# Merging TreeMaps with Common Key

Tags: java

I have 5 Treemaps. In which the key value is same for all treemaps in the range from 0-20 seconds. The value in the treemap differs. I jus want to add the values(values are string, not integer addition).

How is this possible?

For example

```
treemap1 :

Time(key) , co-ordinate(Value)
1,(1,1)
2,(2,4)
...
20 (8,5)


treemap2 :

Time(key) , co-ordinate(Value)
1,(1,5)
2,(9,4)
...
20 (5,6)

...

treemap5 :

Time(key) , co-ordinate(Value)
1,(4,4)
2,(8,1)
...
20 (7,4)



Output:

treemap :

Time(key) , co-ordinate(Value)
1,(1,1)+(1,5)+(4,4)
2,(2,4)+(9,4) +(8,1)
...
20 (8,5)+(5,6)+(7,4)
```

I know, I dont have the code, But I want an idea, how I should write a code for this, so I have asked. Please dont mark it negative due to absence of code.

Comment: @StephenC, Yes, But I was not getting how to keep key same and append the value, not add it. I did not got it.

Comment: @StephenC : Mark it negative mann.

Comment: It's occurred to me that if all the TreeMaps have all 20 keys, then you can do it all in a single loop.  My original answer assumed that some of the TreeMaps would be missing some of the keys.  Can you please confirm whether all the TreeMaps have all of the keys; if so, I shall post a second answer, using just one loop.

Comment: @DavidWallace All the treemap has 20 keys, but each treemap has some additional key also, which i do not want to store.

Comment: OK, then I will post a different solution. That puts a slightly different spin on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a `StringBuilder[21]`, then iterate through the `entrySets` of all the `Maps`, appending the value to the corresponding entry in the array.

Comment: I did not understood the appending part

Comment: Read the javadoc for StringBuilder ... particularly the "append" method.

Comment: (Mind you, I suspect that David might have misunderstood your question because I don't see why you'd need an array of StringBuilders.  You want a treemap as output ...)

Comment: OK, so at the end, you can walk the array, convert the values back into Strings, and shove them back into a TreeMap for the output.  The reason for the array is just that since the keys are the integers from 0 to 20 (or was it 1 to 20?) there doesn't seem to be much point in having a TreeMap for the StringBuilders.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Guava's [Iterables](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html) class:

```
TreeMap<Integer,String> map1 = ...
TreeMap<Integer,String> map2 = ...
TreeMap<Integer,String> map3 = ...
TreeMap<Integer,String> map4 = ...
TreeMap<Integer,String> map5 = ...

final Map<Integer,String> output = new TreeMap<>();

for(final Map.Entry<Integer,String> entry : Iterables.concat(map1.entrySet(), map2.entrySet(), map3.entrySet(), map4.entrySet(), map5.entrySet())) {
    if(!output.containsKey(entry.getKey())) {
      output.put(entry.getKey(), "");
    }
    output.put(entry.getKey(), output.get(entry.getKey())+entry.getValue());
}
```

This will append the values without a separator, if you actually want the plus symbol, then:

```
output.put(entry.getKey(), String.format("%s%s", output.get(entry.getKey()).isEmpty() ? "" : output.get(entry.getKey())+"+", entry.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below. If all the maps have same keys & size otherwise you can generalize the below approach.

TreeMap map1 = new TreeMap();

```
    TreeMap<Integer,String> map2 = new TreeMap<Integer,String>();

    map1.put(1, "(1,1)");
    map1.put(2, "(3,3)");

    map2.put(1, "(2,3)");
    map2.put(2, "(4,4)");

    TreeMap<Integer,String> finalMap = new TreeMap<Integer,String>();

    for(Integer i : map1.keySet()){
        finalMap.put(i, map1.get(i) + "+" + map2.get(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've now added a new condition - that the keys between 1 and 20 are the only ones you care about, and that these keys are in all the maps, you could do something like this.

```
Map<Integer,String> output = new TreeMap<Integer,String>();
for (int i=1; i<=20; i++) {
    output.put(i, map1.get(i)+map2.get(i)+map3.get(i)+map4.get(i)+map5.get(i));
}
```

It's not elegant, but it gets the job done, subject to the conditions that you've stipulated; and it's easy to understand.